# FIll area between 4 points with a color in Macroquad Rust

Tags: user-interface, vector, rust, 3d

I am trying to fill in the area between four points in Macroquad. These points are rotated a lot so the area is not a rectangle.
What I have is 4 Vec variables, I want take the x,y and then fill the area between them.

```rust
a = vec![x1,y1];
b = vec![x2,y2];
c = vec![x3,y3];
d = vec![x4,y4];
```

This is in the context of a rotating 3d cube projected into a 2d plane.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 triangles back to back

`draw_triangle(v1: Vec2, v2: Vec2, v3: Vec2, color: Color)`